# How to make checked attribute work with intermediate option?

Tags: html, angularjs

I have a set of radio buttons for day, month and year.

```
<label>
   <input type="radio" ng-model="IsDays" name="timeunit" > Period in days
   <input type="radio" ng-model="IsMonths" ng-checked="true" name="timeunit"> Period in months
   <input type="radio" ng-model="IsYears" name="timeunit" > Period in years
</label>
```

I have read that *in spite of placing the checked attribute to an intermediary option, **the last button in the group will be checked**, if the radio buttons have the **same name attribute value**.*

I tried this with both *checked* and *ng-checked="true"* scenarios.

Is there an easy way to override this behaviour and allow an intermediate option (*month*) to be checked by default?

**UPDATE**: Solved my own question. Refer to answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Posting the answer for future reference:

Just *checked* will work only if the last radio button option needs to be checked by default.

We need to give *checked="checked"* for this to work for intermediate options. Just *checked* won't work in this case.

```
<label>
 <input type="radio" ng-model="IsDays" name="timeunit" > Period in days
 <input type="radio" ng-model="IsMonths" checked="checked" name="timeunit"> Period in months
 <input type="radio" ng-model="IsYears" name="timeunit" > Period in years
```

Strange :)

**UPDATE:** Even this didn't work after clearing browser cookies. After looking at some AngularJS documentation, I got the following solution.

```
        <label>
            <input type="radio" ng-model="timeunit" value="days">
            Period in days
        </label><br />
        <label>
            <input type="radio" ng-model="timeunit" value="months">
            Period in months
        </label><br />
        <label>
            <input type="radio" ng-model="timeunit" value="years">
            Period in years
        </label><br />
```

Instead of setting same name property, we have to set same value for *ng-model* for all three radio buttons to make them function as a group.

To set the default, we can set it in the js file as follows

```
 function ($scope) {

    $scope.timeunit = "months"; //Default set to months

  //Other code
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [ngInit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit) 
Like:

```
<input type="radio" ng-model="IsMonths" ng-init="checked=true" name="timeunit"> Period in months
```

Comment: Updated solution @Rahul